# how to fix layout of the advertisement banner

Tags: android, admob, android-relativelayout, ads

I have just added ads from admob in my android application. Everything is working fine but there is just a small layout problem. When the use taps on `EditText` and keyboard pops up on the screen the ads sit on top of the keyboard making it look irritating as you can see in the image below. How can i make sure that the ad is fixed at the bottom even when the keyboard is open?

I have used RelativeLayout in the activity and the tag for the ads is as below

```
<com.google.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="<MY ID>" />
```

Activity Declaration in Manifest

```
<activity
        android:name=".MyActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_my_activity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity
        android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|
        uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />"
```

[image: layout of advertisement]

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Check you android manifest and make sure that in your activity tag  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" is **removed**

```
    <activity
        android:name=".YouActivity"
        android:label="@string/activity123"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" /> //remove adjustResize
```

should be

```
    <activity
        android:name=".YouActivity"
        android:label="@string/activity123"/>
```

and try adding android:windowSoftInputMode="" and experiment on what values you can put there (CTRL+SPACE in eclipse). Try "adjustPan".

Comment: remove "screenLayout" from the android:configChanges than try. thanks

Comment: @Geettaunk that dont work either. If i remove anything from `android:configChanges` i get the following error. `You must have AdActivity declared in AndroidManifest.xml with configChanges`

Comment: try adding android:windowSoftInputMode="" and experiment on what values you can put there (CTRL+SPACE in eclipse). Try "adjustPan".